# Laravel 5.7 : Cleanest way to generate nested urls in views

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I currently have nested routes.

Let's say I have

```
Route::resource('a', 'AController');
Route::resource('a.b', 'BController');
Route::resource('a.b.c', 'CController');
```

In my views, is there a better way to generate URL than doing :

`route('a.b.c.show', ['a'=>$aId, 'b'=>$bId, 'c'=>$cId])`

It's getting a little annoying for nested urls. Why can't we just pass an Eloquent model instance? Like `route('a.b.c.show', $cInstance)`

Thank you

Comment: That would require a lot of knowledge for laravel to know how to get a and b from c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often pass the responsibility of generating the url to the model, e.g. with getters:

```
$cInstance->url
```

```php
public function getUrlAttribute() {
    return route('a.b.c.show', $this);
    // or:
    // return action([CController::class, 'show'], ['a' => $this]);
}
```

But it depends on your use case. Normal methods work just as well, like if you want to add more parameters than just what the model knows about already. For example:

```php
public function url($b, $c) {
    return route('a.b.c', ['a' => $this, 'b' => $b, 'c' => $c]);
}
```

However, if you're talking about just getting the ID from a model before using it, like in this case:

```php
$aId = $a->id;
return route('a', ['a' => $aId]);
```

Then Laravel actually *does* support that already: `route('a.b.c.show', compact('a', 'b', 'c'))` should work fine. Eloquent models implement the `Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlRoutable` interface, which has a `getRouteKey()` method that the router understands how to use.